# Hover effect range too high

Tags: html, css, hover

Hey I made a small hover effect but there is a bug in it which I seem not to be able to remove by myself, so hopefully someone can help me :(

`[here]`https://jsfiddle.net/5a4jh4pc/

this is the hover effect.

1. The hover width is not arranged to 100% of the image size
2. The hover effect even starts if you are close to the image on the right side. (it should only do the effect when the mouse is ON the image, not next to it.)

I hope someone can help me here to fix this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your container set to a certain size, which the `hover` effect is triggered over, and the image is set to 70% of this.

This means that you have 30% of the container to the right still activating the `hover`, but containing no image.

Change the `figure` `width` to suit your needs

```
figure {
display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}
figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  color: white;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease;
  -moz-transition:    all 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition:      all 0.6s ease;
      font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
}
figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
figure:hover:before {
  opacity: 0;
}
.cap-bot img {
    float:left;
width:100%;
}
.cap-bot:before { width:0%;padding: 10px 10px;bottom: 10px; }
.cap-bot figcaption { width:100%;padding: 10px 10px;left: 0; bottom: -30%;}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption {width:100%;padding: 10px 10px;bottom: 0; }
```

Forked https://jsfiddle.net/hjhbrosh/

Comment: Hey thank you this worked. If I want to add multiple images next to each other with a padding of 10px would that be possible? because when I try it the hover window becomes 10px wider and higher as well.

Comment: It depends what you're trying to achieve.  You can use `box-sizing: border-box;` to contain the size of the hover area to suppress the padding?

Comment: well what I am trying to do is a "Team page" with the images of each Team member and the certain text about it. The modified css code which you posted above helps with the effect issue. But if I add all images now (8 of them) they are basically glued together. would there be a way to push them a bit away from each other.

Comment: have you tried using `margin` instead of padding?  Padding is internal spacing (i.e. you are padding out the box, like if you were packing an actual box) whereas the margin is the external boundary.

Comment: see this https://jsfiddle.net/hjhbrosh/1/ for an example of margin-right in a team photo page

Answer (score 1):

Remove left and right padding in your `figcaption` and use `word-wrap: break-word;` to wrap the text to the next line when it overflows and use a `div` inside your `figcaption` to retain that padding.

```
.cap-bot figcaption { 
    width:70%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    left: 0; 
    bottom: -30%;
}
.cap-bot:hover figcaption {
    width:70%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    bottom: 0; 
}
```

Check this [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/5a4jh4pc/4/)